# Align circles and Balls are not bouncing

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

I am trying to place a big circle in the center of the screen and four other circles on the right side. How can I achieve this? Also, there should be balls bouncing inside the small circles on the right, and only one ball is inside each of them instead of several. An alert should be triggered by the big main circle. From the small circles, there should be no alert. How can I solve this problem? I am thankful for any help. Thanks in advance.

```js
var noop = function() {
  return this;
};

function UserCanceledError() {
  this.name = 'UserCanceledError';
  this.message = 'User canceled dialog';
}
UserCanceledError.prototype = Object.create(Error.prototype);

function Dialog() {
  this.setCallbacks(noop, noop);
}
Dialog.prototype.setCallbacks = function(okCallback, cancelCallback) {
  this._okCallback     = okCallback;
  return this;
};
Dialog.prototype.waitForUser = function() {
  var _this = this;
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    _this.setCallbacks(resolve, reject);
  });
};

Dialog.prototype.show = noop;
Dialog.prototype.hide = noop;

function PromptDialog() {
  Dialog.call(this);
  this.el           = document.getElementById('dialog');
  this.messageEl    = this.el.querySelector('.message');
  this.okButton     = this.el.querySelector('button.ok');
  this.attachDomEvents();
}
PromptDialog.prototype = Object.create(Dialog.prototype);
PromptDialog.prototype.attachDomEvents = function() {
  var _this = this;
  this.okButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
    _this.hide();
    console.log('Ok clicked!!');
  });
  
};
PromptDialog.prototype.show = function(message) {
  this.messageEl.innerHTML = '' + message;
  this.el.className = '';
  return this;
};
PromptDialog.prototype.hide = function() {
  this.el.className = 'hidden';
  return this;
};
const ctx = document.getElementById("Canvas").getContext("2d");
const containerR = 150;
const size = containerR * 2
ctx.canvas.width = ctx.canvas.height = size;
ctx.globalAlpha = 0.8;

//Adding fourcircles to the right
const ctx1 = document.getElementById("Canvas1").getContext("2d");
const ctx2 = document.getElementById("Canvas2").getContext("2d");
const ctx3 = document.getElementById("Canvas3").getContext("2d");
const ctx4 = document.getElementById("Canvas4").getContext("2d");
const containerR2 = 80;
const size2 = containerR2 * 2
ctx1.canvas.width = ctx1.canvas.height = size2;
ctx2.canvas.width = ctx2.canvas.height = size2;
ctx3.canvas.width = ctx3.canvas.height = size2;
ctx4.canvas.width = ctx4.canvas.height = size2;
ctx1.globalAlpha = 0.8;
ctx2.globalAlpha = 0.8;
ctx3.globalAlpha = 0.8;
ctx4.globalAlpha = 0.8;


var prompt = new PromptDialog();

const getBall = (x, y, dx, dy, r, color) => ({x, y, dx, dy, r, color});

const balls = [
  getBall(size / 2, size - 30, 0.1, 0.1, 8, "Green"),
  getBall(size / 3, size - 50, 0.1, 0.1, 8, "Green"),
  getBall(size / 4, size - 60, 0.1, 0.1, 8, "Green"),
  getBall(size / 2, size / 5,  0.1, 0.1, 8,  "Green"),
];

const drawBall = (ball) => {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(ball.x, ball.y, ball.r, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
  ctx.fillStyle = ball.collider ? "red" : ball.color;
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx1.beginPath();
  ctx1.arc(ball.x, ball.y, ball.r, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
  ctx1.fillStyle = ball.collider ? "red" : ball.color;
  ctx1.fill();
  ctx1.closePath();
  ctx2.beginPath();
  ctx2.arc(ball.x, ball.y, ball.r, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
  ctx2.fillStyle = ball.collider ? "red" : ball.color;
  ctx2.fill();
  ctx2.closePath();
  ctx3.beginPath();
  ctx3.arc(ball.x, ball.y, ball.r, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
  ctx3.fillStyle = ball.collider ? "red" : ball.color;
  ctx3.fill();
  ctx3.closePath();
  ctx4.beginPath();
  ctx4.arc(ball.x, ball.y, ball.r, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
  ctx4.fillStyle = ball.collider ? "red" : ball.color;
  ctx4.fill();
  ctx4.closePath();
}

const updatePos = (ball) => {

  ball.x += ball.dx;
  ball.y += ball.dy;
  const dx = ball.x - containerR;
  const dy = ball.y - containerR;

  if (Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy) >= containerR - ball.r) {
    const v = Math.sqrt(ball.dx * ball.dx + ball.dy * ball.dy);
    const angleToCollisionPoint = Math.atan2(-dy, dx);
    const oldAngle = Math.atan2(-ball.dy, ball.dx);
    const newAngle = 2 * angleToCollisionPoint - oldAngle;
    ball.dx = -v * Math.cos(newAngle);
    ball.dy = v * Math.sin(newAngle);
  }
}


const collides = (a, b) => (Math.hypot(Math.abs(a.x - b.x), Math.abs(a.y - b.y)) < (a.r + b.r));

function engine() {
  //console.clear(); // Clear console test messages
  mydiv.textContent =" ";
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);
  ctx1.clearRect(0, 0, ctx1.canvas.width, ctx1.canvas.height);
  ctx2.clearRect(0, 0, ctx2.canvas.width, ctx2.canvas.height);
  ctx3.clearRect(0, 0, ctx3.canvas.width, ctx3.canvas.height);
  ctx4.clearRect(0, 0, ctx4.canvas.width, ctx4.canvas.height);

  balls.forEach((a, ai) => {
    a.collider = undefined;
    
    balls.forEach((b, bi) => {
      if (bi === ai) return; // Don't look at self
      if (collides(a, b)) a.collider = b; // Store the colliding B ball
    });
    
    if (a.collider) { // If ball has a collider:
     //mydiv.textContent = ("Alert");
     beep();
     prompt.show('ALERT!!!!! Not Maintaining Distance')
      .waitForUser()
      .then(function(name) {
        output.innerHTML = '' + name;
      })
      .catch(function(e) {
        console.log('Unknown error', e);
      })
      .finally(function() {
        prompt.hide();
      });
      
      //console.log(`${a.color[0]} → ← ${a.collider.color[0]}`);
    }
    updatePos(a);
    drawBall(a);

  });

  requestAnimationFrame(engine);
}

engine();
```

```css
canvas {
  background: #eee;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 4px #000;
}
.row {
  display: flex;
}

.container1 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-left: 70%;
  margin-top: 8%;
  float: right;
}

#Canvas1, #Canvas2, #Canvas3, #Canvas4 {
    background: #eee;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: solid 1px #000;
    margin: 4px;
}
```

```html
<div class="column">
    <canvas id="Canvas"></canvas>
  </div>
<div class="container1">
  <div class="row">
    <canvas id="Canvas1"></canvas>
    <div><p>abc</p></div>
    <canvas id="Canvas2"></canvas>
    <div><p>def</p></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <canvas id="Canvas3"></canvas>
    <div><p>hij</p></div>
    <canvas id="Canvas4"></canvas>
    <div><p>klm</p></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="mydiv"></div>
<div id="y"></div>
<div id="dx"></div>
<div id="dy"></div>
<div id="dialog" class="hidden">
  <div class="message"></div>
  <div>
    <button class="ok">OK</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a lot of errors in the provided code:

- `beep()` fonction is not defined, it prevents the alert system to work.
- there is only one list of the same 4 balls for the 5 canvas, so you see the same 4 balls in all canvas.
- `updatePos` uses `containerR` that is a global variable (radius of the big circle), calculations can only be done for the big circle.
- `drawBall` draws the same single ball in the 5 contexts

Fixed code, with random initial positions for balls :

```js
function PromptDialog(dialog) {
  this.el           = document.getElementById(dialog);
  this.messageEl    = this.el.querySelector('.message');
  this.okButton     = this.el.querySelector('button.ok');
  this.attachDomEvents();
}
 PromptDialog.prototype.attachDomEvents = function() {
  this.okButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    this.hide();
    //console.log('Ok clicked!!');
  });
};
PromptDialog.prototype.show = function(message) {
  this.messageEl.innerHTML = '' + message;
  this.el.className = '';
};
PromptDialog.prototype.hide = function() {
  this.el.className = 'hidden';
};


var prompt = new PromptDialog('dialog');

const getBall = (x, y, dx, dy, r, color) => ({x, y, dx, dy, r, color});

const drawBall = (ball, ctx) => {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(ball.x, ball.y, ball.r, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
  ctx.fillStyle = ball.collider ? "red" : ball.color;
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.closePath();
}

const updatePos = (ball, containerR) => {

  ball.x += ball.dx;
  ball.y += ball.dy;
  const dx = ball.x - containerR;
  const dy = ball.y - containerR;

  if (Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy) >= containerR - ball.r) {
    const v = Math.sqrt(ball.dx * ball.dx + ball.dy * ball.dy);
    const angleToCollisionPoint = Math.atan2(-dy, dx);
    const oldAngle = Math.atan2(-ball.dy, ball.dx);
    const newAngle = 2 * angleToCollisionPoint - oldAngle;
    ball.dx = -v * Math.cos(newAngle);
    ball.dy = v * Math.sin(newAngle);
  }
}

function makeArea(domid, radius, ballsNumber, alerts) {
  const ctx = document.getElementById(domid).getContext("2d");
  const containerR = radius;
  const size = radius * 2
  ctx.canvas.width = ctx.canvas.height = size;
  ctx.globalAlpha = 0.8;
  
  const balls = [];
  const speed = 0.1;
  
  for(var i=0 ; i<ballsNumber ; ++i) {
    const r = Math.random()*radius*0.5;
    const t = Math.random()*Math.PI*2;
    const t2 = Math.random()*Math.PI*2;
    
    balls.push(
     getBall(
       radius + Math.cos(t)*r,
        radius + Math.sin(t)*r,
        Math.cos(t2)*speed,
        Math.sin(t2)*speed,
        8,
        "Green")
    );
  }
  
  return {
    ctx: ctx,
    radius: radius,
    balls: balls,
    alerts:alerts
  }
}

const collides = (a, b) => (Math.hypot(Math.abs(a.x - b.x), Math.abs(a.y - b.y)) < (a.r + b.r));

const areas = [
  makeArea("Canvas", 150, 4, true),
  makeArea("Canvas1", 80, 4, false),
  makeArea("Canvas2", 80, 4, false),
  makeArea("Canvas3", 80, 4, false),
  makeArea("Canvas4", 80, 4, false)
];

function engine() {
  //console.clear(); // Clear console test messages
  areas.forEach((area) =>{
    const ctx = area.ctx;
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);
    area.balls.forEach((a, ai) => {
      a.collider = undefined;

      area.balls.forEach((b, bi) => {
        if (bi === ai) return; // Don't look at self
        if (collides(a, b)) a.collider = b; // Store the colliding B ball
      });

      if (a.collider && area.alerts) { // If ball has a collider:
       //beep();
       prompt.show('ALERT!!!!! Not Maintaining Distance');

        //console.log(`${a.color[0]} → ← ${a.collider.color[0]}`);
      }
      updatePos(a, area.radius);
      drawBall(a, ctx);
    });
  });
  requestAnimationFrame(engine);
}

engine();
```

```css
canvas {
  background: #eee;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 4px #000;
}
.row {
  display: flex;
}

.hidden {
  display:none;
}

#Canvas1, #Canvas2, #Canvas3, #Canvas4 {
  background: #eee;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: solid 1px #000;
  margin: 4px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
    <div>
        <canvas id="Canvas"></canvas>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div class="row">
            <canvas id="Canvas1"></canvas>
            <div><p>abc</p></div>
            <canvas id="Canvas2"></canvas>
            <div><p>def</p></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <canvas id="Canvas3"></canvas>
            <div><p>hij</p></div>
            <canvas id="Canvas4"></canvas>
            <div><p>klm</p></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="dialog" class="hidden">
    <div class="message"></div>
    <div>
        <button class="ok">OK</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for you support. But i need an alert should be triggered by the big main circle. From the small circles, there should be no alert. Then i want the big circle to be in the center and right side should be the small circles...

Comment: You have everything to do that easily in the above code.

Comment: I tried to get alert from big one but if i do so it shows nothing and also when I try to get text below circle also not coming